# Auto change second dropdown when selecting the first option

Tags: javascript, html, html-select, dropdown

I have two dropdowns, Selecting the first one should change the second automatically. Both dropdowns are visible always.

I have created a fiddle to get you started. Can you help me out. Thanks!

**HTML**  [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hive/p48r2tgx/)

```
<select name="" id="">
     <option value="">-</option>
     <option value="">Apple</option>
     <option value="">Orange</option>
     <option value="">Cucumber</option> <!-- veg -->
     <option value="">Banana</option>
     <option value="">Grapes</option>
     <option value="">Onion</option>    <!-- veg -->
     <option value="">Tomato</option>   <!-- veg -->
</select>

<select name="" id="">
    <option value="">-</option>
    <option value="">Fruit</option>
    <option value="">Vegetable</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Use `data-*` attributes to differentiate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `data-*` attribute to differentiate among `fruit` and `vegetable`

```js
var category = document.getElementById('category');
document.getElementById('elements').onchange = function() {
  var optionSelected = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
  if (optionSelected.textContent != '-') {
    if (optionSelected.dataset.val === 'veg') {
      category.value = 'veg';
    } else {
      category.value = 'fruit';
    }
  } else {
    category.value = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="" id="elements">
  <option value="">-</option>
  <option value="">Apple</option>
  <option value="">Orange</option>
  <option data-val='veg' value="">Cucumber</option>
  <!-- veg -->
  <option value="">Banana</option>
  <option value="">Grapes</option>
  <option data-val='veg' value="">Onion</option>
  <!-- veg -->
  <option data-val='veg' value="">Tomato</option>
  <!-- veg -->
</select>

<select name="" id="category">
  <option value="">-</option>
  <option value="fruit">Fruit</option>
  <option value="veg">Vegetable</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery it is simpler.

This is your jQuery code.

```
$('#item').on('change',function(){


$('#category').val($(this) .find("option:selected").attr('data-category'));
});
```

This is the modified HTML

```
<select name="" id="item">
<option value="">-</option>
<option data-category ="fruit" value="">Apple</option>
<option data-category ="fruit" value="">Orange</option>
<option data-category ="vegetable">Cucumber</option>
<option data-category ="fruit" value="">Banana</option>
<option data-category ="fruit" value="">Grapes</option>
<option data-category ="vegetable">Onion</option>
</select>

<select name="" id="category">
   <option value="">-</option>
   <option value="fruit">Fruit</option>
   <option value="vegetable">Vegetables</option>
</select>
```